# StepSize in SpinnerNumberModel java

Tags: java, spinner, jtextfield

I creates a spinner with an Integer [`SpinnerNumberModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html).

```
SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(value, min, max, step);
```

**Base on docs.oracle:**

> stepSize - the difference between elements of the sequence

What does this exactly mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html):

> Changes the size of the value change computed by the getNextValue and
>   getPreviousValue methods.

It's just like having a for-loop like this:

```
for (int i = min; i <= max; i += step)
```

If min is zero and max is 10:

With a step of 1, the sequence is

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

With a step of 2, the sequence is

```
0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```